# Como sobre poner una imagen png sobre otra

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

necesito mostrar al usuario una imagen en este caso esta con el id fondo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al mismo tiempo superponer sobre esta de forma oculta esta segunda imagen a la que llamo el id mascara, de manera que cuando el usuario de  de click a un personaje en realidad de click a un color y de esa manera disparando un evento especifico al detectar el color correspondiente a una accion determinada, Agradesco la ayuda que me puedan brindar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo mi codigo en CODE OPEN https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/ZqxgMo

Comment: No puedo poner esto como respuesta pues no sé si es exactamente lo que buscas, pero puedes usar [HTML Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) para crear áreas dentro de tu imagen que cada una tenga una acción distinta. El [ejemplo de W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) lo usa para crear links a partir de la imagen, sin embargo con figuras tan completas como tus siluetas no parece muy viable "mapear" toda la imagen. Te sugeriría recortar la imagen y agregar a cada sección de la imagen su propia acción.

Comment: che lo que pidieron es axactamente con imagenes. tambien quise hacerlo con coordenadas pero me dijeron que debo resolver el problema de esta forma

Comment: Puedes separar la imagen en la base + 4 Canvas, dividiendo las image-data en secciones de  píxel y revisar si el pixel seleccionado es transparente para cada sección. Revisa esta pregunta en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487569/click-through-png-image-only-if-clicked-coordinate-is-transparent

Comment: aun necesitare sobre poner ambas imagenes y la mascara oculta

Comment: Hola, No necesariamente tienes que tener una base. Lo que debes hacer es dividir la imagen en 4 distintas. Cada imagen debe contener un personaje y el resto en transparencia. Luego puedes hacer overlapping de las imágenes y detectar donde se hace click guiándote de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487569/click-through-png-image-only-if-clicked-coordinate-is-transparent).